# In spark, how do I fold my RDD into pairs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have an RDD of integers that looks like this:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

(ie there are eight items on the RDD)

and I want to fold the RDD into pairs so it looks like this:

```
((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)
```

(ie there are four items on the RDD).

I thought that there might be a partition or aggregate function but there doesn't seem to be one.

My question is: **In spark, how do I fold my RDD into pairs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what exactly `sliding` function does which available in `mllib` Library

```
// Import the mllib library
scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

scala> val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[10] at parallelize at 
 <console>:29

scala> rdd.sliding(2,2).map(x => (x(0), x(1))).foreach(println)
(1,2)
(5,6)
(3,4)
(7,8)
```

Or better

```
rdd.sliding(2,2).map{case Array(x,y) => (x,y) }.foreach(println)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Amazing work. Just thought it wouldn’t require a library import.